# Infected tails dvd

Tags: security

if a RAT hits my computer and it is NOT the kind that can write to firmware, and I am using my tor tails livecd, and I have no HDD installed on the computer, can this kind of (non-firmware writing) RAT write to my livecd on my dvd player? Or would only a firmware writing RAT be able to write to the livecd?

2...along those same lines, If i download tails iso to a separate computer - (not the computer I will use TAILS on) and someone is on my computer and they send a RAT to this downloaded iso file, or to the dvd with the burned completed tails file/ livecd, will this RAT be permanent on the dvd such that whenever i use it for TAILS livecd, there will always be an active RAT?

thx - newbie!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible yes, but that is why they include the checksum on the site.
If you make a checksum of the iso it has to equal the one on the site.
If not... the file was changed.

This is the same if you download the iso. You should check the site for the recommended way to download and verify the ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Checksums and anything else to give "optimism" can be spoofed as well as the whole entire LiveCD image and tails.org https.  NSA and FBI do anything they want.

If you get a RAT onto your LiveDVD it would write to the bios firmware or create an encrypted memory container on every computer you take it to.  It would AUTO-LOAD into the memory for example.

To them they think everyone in their sheep pen should be gracious that they only steal most of what everyone has and not everything.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the device itself is a read-only one, it lacks a writing laser, so even with firmware owned by RAT - it can't change a wave length of the diode in your read-only drive and "make it to write"
2. yes - in case if it's sent to DVD iso, that's the only reason to make a drop-in into an image: it's hilarious to insert the RAT but not make it auto-loading, it just won't work and will expose the whole hack attempt